# how to scale a matrix by group?

Tags: r, matrix, scale

I have a example data as follows, I want to scale `x, y, z` by `sex`, and return the same data structure. how to write the code to make it happen. I can successfully scale just one column but not a matrix `my.df` by group `sex`. could someone help me, thanks in advance.
Additionally, if I just scale the matrix `my.df`, not by `sex`, the `scale` works well.

```
set.seed(2016)
my.df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100, mean=10), 
                        y=rnorm(100, mean=33),
                        z=runif(100,1,300),
                        sex=sample(c("M","F"), 100, rep=T), 
                        group=gl(5, 20, labels=LETTERS[1:5]))
```

the following codes do not work at all.

```
library(plyr)
ddply(my.df, .(sex), transform, scale)
apply(my.df, 2, function(x) ddply(x, .(my.df$sex), scale(x)))
apply(my.df[1:3], 2, function(x) tapply(x, my.df$sex, scale))
```

Comment: I think you can try this `by(my.df[,c(-4,-5)], my.df$sex, scale)`.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work for a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(my.df)`, grouped by 'sex', selecting the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, we loop through the columns (`lapply(.SD, ...`) , do the `scale` and convert to `vector`.  (The `scale` function output a matrix with some attributes, which will create some problems if we don't convert to `vector`.)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my.df)[, c('x', 'y', 'z') := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
          as.vector(scale(x))) , by = sex, .SDcols= x:z]
```

Comment: and now I have a matrix with 200 columns, how should I modified the code to automatically read the colnames in c('x','y','z') and .SDcols = x:z. @akrun

Comment: @TaoZhang You can use the `names` i.e. if you want columns `2:190` to be scaled, i.e. `setDT(my.df)[, names(mydf)[2:190] := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.vector(scale(x))), by = sex, .SDcols= 2:190]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. @akrun   :)